# Looking to get a CSS for Apple type drop-down list/menus

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to find a CSS example that does Apple style drop down lists and buttons.  I have browsed Google for some time now and I can't figure out exactly what I should be searching for.  I tried "Apple style CSS buttons and drop down list" and other such search phrases.

Something similar to the following image.
http://www.macdvdripper.org/mac-dvd-to-apple-tv-converter/dvd2appletv-mac-settings.jpg

Thanks guys :)

Comment: SO is **NOT** a _"get a coder for free"_ site, you have to do some work yourself, then we shall help to the best of our ability :-)

Comment: What css have you tried?

Comment: Oh I'll admit I know very little in CSS, I was just looking for some kind of tutorial I can follow and make it myself.  I wasn't looking for some copy-paste code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used these. They're themeroller compatible so you can do a lot with the styling.

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: This is what I was looking for but it has no tutorial of how to do it.  I will manage because I couldn't find anything else on the net.  Thanks guys.  Going to accept this one because it is what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?  http://www.kriesi.at/archives/apple-menu-improved-with-jquery

Edit:

If you're trying to style the select you may have problems:  http://www.electrictoolbox.com/style-select-optgroup-options-css/

One option might be to "simulate" a drop down with css & jquery: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Comment: Sweet.  I need to add few more letters here before I can add this comment.

Comment: I looked at that one, and thats not exactly what I was going for.  I already have menu's, I just want this to be within the actual body of the page.  I want to use the dropdown menu's to select values for numbers and options.  I'll keep working on my code and I'll post it up here to show where I'm at